# Expectation value of Pauli strings for VQE

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe, pauli-gates

I am studying VQE and have boiled it down to a matter of determining the expectation value of Pauli strings:
$$\langle H \rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i \langle\psi|\hat{P_i}|\psi\rangle.$$

I have been trying to implement this for the (arbitrary) 2 qubit Pauli string $XY$.

To evaluate the expectation value wrt. some prepared state classically, I have tried the following:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.opflow import X, Y, Z, I
from qiskit.opflow.state_fns import CircuitStateFn

op = X^Y

q = QuantumRegister(2)

psi = QuantumCircuit(q)

# State preperation
psi.rx(2.3,q[0])
psi.ry(1.4,q[0])
psi.rx(2.1,q[1])
psi.ry(3.1,q[1])
psi = CircuitStateFn(psi)

print(psi.adjoint().compose(op).compose(psi).eval().real)
-> 0.01565372111279102
```

To implement this in a quantum circuit, I would apply the X gate to the 1st qubit and the Y gate to the second. I would then use rotation gates to map the X and Y eigenstates to the Z eigenstates for measurement. It is then my understanding that I can find the expectation value by adding the probabilities for each state multiplied with the eigenvalues of each qubit state. I prepare the circuit using:

```
q = QuantumRegister(2)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)

psi = QuantumCircuit(q)
psi.rx(2.3,q[0])
psi.ry(1.4,q[0])
psi.rx(2.1,q[1])
psi.ry(3.1,q[1])

psi.x(q[0])
psi.y(q[1])

psi.u2(0,np.pi,q[0]) # X -> Z
psi.u2(0,np.pi/2,q[1]) # Y -> Z

psi.measure_all()
```

and treat the results using

```
shots = 8192*2
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(psi, backend, shots=shots)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts()

expectation_value = 0
for (state,num) in counts.items():
    sign = (state.count('1') % 2) * (-1)
    expectation_value += sign * num/shots

print(expectation_value)
-> -0.21575927734375
```

Which clearly does not give the same result. Where do I go wrong? I have largely based my intuition on this great github page: https://github.com/DavitKhach/quantum-algorithms-tutorials/blob/master/variational_quantum_eigensolver.ipynb and then done some proofs to verify the results.

Answer (score 1):

To measure $\langle XY \rangle$ you need to apply $H$ gate to the first qubit since  $HZH = X$, and $S^\dagger$ follow by $H$ to the second qubit since $(SH)Z(HS^\dagger) = Y $.

[image]

Now, Qiskit uses little endian convention, the order of qubit going backward. So $H$ to the second qubit and $S^\dagger$ follow by $H$ to the first qubit.

Comment: Hi, my U2 rotation gates actually perform the exact transformation that you describe (I checked by algebra to make sure). Still I am not getting the right results, also after fixing the issue that @Egretta.Thula brought up. Am I not supposed to apply the X and Y operators before the rotation before measurement? Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue mentioned by [@KAJ226](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/9858/kaj226) in his answer, this line of code is wrong

```
sign = (state.count('1') % 2) * (-1)
```

because `sign` will equal $0$ for even number of $1$s. You should use something like that:

```
sign = 1 if state.count('1') % 2 == 0 else -1
```

Or,

```
sign = (-1) ** (state.count('1') % 2)
```

---

**Note 1**: For a better performance use Aer simulators (C++ based) instead of BasicAer simulators (Python-based). That is:

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
```

---

**Note 2**: To calculate the expectation value using a backend (simulator or quantum computer), you don't need to modify the circuit nor loop through the counts to add the probabilities multiplied by the eigenvalues. You can use Qiskit's [`ExpectationFactory`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.expectations.ExpectationFactory.html) and [`CircuitSampler`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.converters.CircuitSampler.html):

```
measurable_expression =  ~StateFn(op) @ StateFn(psi)

exp_converter = ExpectationFactory.build(op, backend)
expect_op = exp_converter.convert(measurable_expression)
sampled_op = CircuitSampler(backend).convert(expect_op)
expectation_value = sampled_op.eval().real
```

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, I've fixed the sign thing. Still I do not get the right results, so something else in my approach must be wrong. I now get the expectation value 0.56.

Comment: Did you take @KAJ226 answer into consideration?